# Slick carousel переход на страницу window.location.href не работает

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

есть карусель на  Slick  появилась идея при просмотре последнего слайда сделать переход на определённую страницу  попробовал такой вариант

**infinite: true** заменил на **false**

и добалил код

$('.slick-next.slick-disabled').on('click',function(){

window.location.href('http://test.web-devsoltan.com/personazhi/');
});

**Почему не срабатывает код?**

[**[codepen][1](https://codepen.io/Viorel/pen/MVKLGV)**](https://codepen.io/Viorel/pen/MVKLGV)

[1](https://codepen.io/Viorel/pen/MVKLGV):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.hero-carousel').slick({
    centerMode: false,
    infinite: flase,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    arrows: true,
    prevArrow: '<span class="icon-angle-left"></span>',
    nextArrow: '<span class="icon-angle-right"></span>'


  });

  $('.slick-next.slick-disabled').on('click', function() {

    window.location.href('http://test.web-devsoltan.com/personazhi/');
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://test.web-devsoltan.com/wp-content/themes/entertainment/libs/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://test.web-devsoltan.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<link href="https://test.web-devsoltan.com/wp-content/themes/entertainment/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://test.web-devsoltan.com/wp-content/themes/entertainment/libs/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<section class="hero">
  <div class="section_title">
    <h2>Наши герои</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x grid-margin-x hero-carousel">

      <div class="slick-slider-item cell medium-6">
        <img width="320" height="320" src="https://test.web-devsoltan.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/hero1.jpg" class="attachment-full size-full" alt="" srcset="https://test.web-devsoltan.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/hero1.jpg 320w, http://test.web-devsoltan.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/hero1-150x150.jpg 150w, https://test.web-devsoltan.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/hero1-300x300.jpg 300w"
          sizes="(max-width: 320px) 100vw, 320px" />
        <p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
      </div>
      <div class="slick-slider-item cell medium-6">
        <img width="320" height="320" src="https://test.web-devsoltan.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/hero2.jpg" class="attachment-full size-full" alt="" srcset="https://test.web-devsoltan.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/hero2.jpg 320w, http://test.web-devsoltan.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/hero2-150x150.jpg 150w, https://test.web-devsoltan.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/hero2-300x300.jpg 300w"
          sizes="(max-width: 320px) 100vw, 320px" />
        <p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
      </div>
      <div class="slick-slider-item cell medium-6">
        <img width="320" height="320" src="https://test.web-devsoltan.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/hero3.jpg" class="attachment-full size-full" alt="" srcset="https://test.web-devsoltan.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/hero3.jpg 320w, https://test.web-devsoltan.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/hero3-150x150.jpg 150w, https://test.web-devsoltan.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/hero3-300x300.jpg 300w"
          sizes="(max-width: 320px) 100vw, 320px" />
        <p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
      </div>
      <div class="slick-slider-item cell medium-6">
        <img width="320" height="320" src="https://test.web-devsoltan.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/hero4.jpg" class="attachment-full size-full" alt="" srcset="https://test.web-devsoltan.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/hero4.jpg 320w, http://test.web-devsoltan.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/hero4-150x150.jpg 150w, https://test.web-devsoltan.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/hero4-300x300.jpg 300w"
          sizes="(max-width: 320px) 100vw, 320px" />
        <p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
      </div>
      <div class="slick-slider-item cell medium-6">
        <img width="320" height="320" src="https://test.web-devsoltan.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/hero1.jpg" class="attachment-full size-full" alt="" srcset="https://test.web-devsoltan.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/hero1.jpg 320w, http://test.web-devsoltan.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/hero1-150x150.jpg 150w, https://test.web-devsoltan.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/hero1-300x300.jpg 300w"
          sizes="(max-width: 320px) 100vw, 320px" />
        <p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
      </div>
      <div class="slick-slider-item cell medium-6">
        <img width="320" height="320" src="https://test.web-devsoltan.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/hero2.jpg" class="attachment-full size-full" alt="" srcset="https://test.web-devsoltan.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/hero2.jpg 320w, http://test.web-devsoltan.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/hero2-150x150.jpg 150w, https://test.web-devsoltan.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/hero2-300x300.jpg 300w"
          sizes="(max-width: 320px) 100vw, 320px" />
        <p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: А что, в тег `<a>...</a>` обернуть нельзя?

Comment: просто я вставил на wordpress с помощью php думал есть решение быстрее что бы не переделывать весь код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.location.href` - это не функция, а свойство объекта location.

Таким образом, чтобы сменить адрес, нужно присвоить `href` новое значение:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.hero-carousel').slick({
    centerMode: false,
    infinite: flase,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    arrows: true,
    prevArrow: '<span class="icon-angle-left"></span>',
    nextArrow: '<span class="icon-angle-right"></span>'


  });

  $('.slick-next.slick-disabled').on('click', function() {

    window.location.href = 'http://test.web-devsoltan.com/personazhi/';
  });

});
```

Comment: Это решит вопрос с переходом, но не с логикой вашего приложения. Если кликнуть по кнопке, которая задизейблится, то ничего не произойдет. Необходимо отслеживать, на каком вы слайде находитесь, и если этот слайд последний, то делать редирект. Нужен коллбэк `afterChange`, у Slick есть такой